# Why does checking keys on my imported object fail on the second test?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I have an object

```
let itemStore = {};
module.exports = itemStore;
```

and some items

```
let itemStore = require('./itemStore');
let item = function() {
  let a = Math.random();
  let self = {
    rand: a,
    b: 'hello world'
  };
  itemStore[a] = self;
  return self;
}
module.exports = item;
```

I create an item and it stores itself in the store object. I don't quite like the pattern, but I inherited the project.

So I had problems and wrote this test case:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  let item = require('./item.js');
  let itemStore = require('./itemStore.js');

  let inspect = function() {
    return Object.keys(itemStore).length;
  }
  let equals = function(a, b) {
    console.log("Expected " + b + ", was " + a);
  }

  let test = function() {
    equals(inspect(), 0);
    let subject = item();
    equals(inspect(), 1);
    let subject2 = item();
    equals(inspect(), 2);
    itemStore = {};
    equals(inspect(), 0);
  }
  test();
  console.log('-----------------');
  test();
})();
```

And by running

```
node itemTest.js
```

I get this funky output:

```
Expected 0, was 0
Expected 1, was 1
Expected 2, was 2
Expected 0, was 0
-----------------
Expected 0, was 0
Expected 1, was 0
Expected 2, was 0
Expected 0, was 0
```

You see, the second run is inexplicable to me.

I put it on github:
https://github.com/janlimpens/js_static

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `itemStore` that is used by `item.js` is the object exported by `itemStore.js`:

```
let itemStore = require('./itemStore');
...
itemStore[a] = self;
```

In `itemTest`, you reassign `itemStore` to an empty object *disconnected* from the `itemStore` used in `item.js` at the end of the `test` function:

```
let itemStore = require('./itemStore.js');
...
let test = function() {
  ...
  itemStore = {};  // <---- itemStore is a new object,\
                   // disconnected from the one in itemStore.js
  equals(inspect(), 0);
}
```

The new empty `itemStore` object is only referenceable inside of `itemTest.js` - `item.js` will continue to reference the object created in the *other module*, `itemStore.js`. So, further calls of `item()` will put items on the *old object*, but not the new object - and your `inspect()` will inspect the new object after the reassignment near the end of the first `test()` call.

Either don't reassign the `itemStore` at all, or have `itemStore.js` export a function allowing for the reassignment of the object it uses (while having another function that, when called, returns the current object it's using).

Comment: That's interesting! So you suggest something like itemStore.items and itemStore.clear()?

Comment: Would you mind having a look at https://github.com/janlimpens/js_static to see my fixes? Would "How to avoid breaking the reference to an external object" make for a better title?

Comment: A plain object with an `items` property and a function might be a bit easier: https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/5f820715f5bbe33d9ea0f2d5e90aee78